# NameError: global name 'company_id' is not defined - Odoo v10 community

Tags: python, odoo

I'm migrating some modules from v7 to v10 of Odoo community version.

Right now, I've modified this method, it looks like this:

```
class ResPartner(models.Model):
_inherit = 'res.partner'

@api.multi
@api.depends('company_id')
def _get_country_code(self):
    """
    Return the country code of the user company. If not exists, return XX.
    """
    context = dict(self._context or {})
    user_company = self.env['res.users'].browse(company_id)
    return user_company.partner_id and user_company.partner_id.country_id \
        and user_company.partner_id.country_id.code or 'XX'
```

But every time I try to go to a `res.partner` view, it throws me this error:

```
Odoo Server Error

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/kristian/.virtualenvs/odoov10/lib/python2.7/site-packages/odoo-10.0rc1c_20161005-py2.7.egg/odoo/http.py", line 638, in _handle_exception
return super(JsonRequest, self)._handle_exception(exception)
File "/home/kristian/.virtualenvs/odoov10/lib/python2.7/site-packages/odoo-10.0rc1c_20161005-py2.7.egg/odoo/http.py", line 675, in dispatch
result = self._call_function(**self.params)
File "/home/kristian/.virtualenvs/odoov10/lib/python2.7/site-packages/odoo-10.0rc1c_20161005-py2.7.egg/odoo/http.py", line 331, in _call_function
return checked_call(self.db, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/kristian/.virtualenvs/odoov10/lib/python2.7/site-packages/odoo-10.0rc1c_20161005-py2.7.egg/odoo/service/model.py", line 119, in wrapper
return f(dbname, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/kristian/.virtualenvs/odoov10/lib/python2.7/site-packages/odoo-10.0rc1c_20161005-py2.7.egg/odoo/http.py", line 324, in checked_call
result = self.endpoint(*a, **kw)
File "/home/kristian/.virtualenvs/odoov10/lib/python2.7/site-packages/odoo-10.0rc1c_20161005-py2.7.egg/odoo/http.py", line 933, in __call__
return self.method(*args, **kw)
File "/home/kristian/.virtualenvs/odoov10/lib/python2.7/site-packages/odoo-10.0rc1c_20161005-py2.7.egg/odoo/http.py", line 504, in response_wrap
response = f(*args, **kw)
File "/home/kristian/odoov10/odoo-10.0rc1c-20161005/odoo/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 862, in call_kw
return self._call_kw(model, method, args, kwargs)
File "/home/kristian/odoov10/odoo-10.0rc1c-20161005/odoo/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 854, in _call_kw
return call_kw(request.env[model], method, args, kwargs)
File "/home/kristian/.virtualenvs/odoov10/lib/python2.7/site-packages/odoo-10.0rc1c_20161005-py2.7.egg/odoo/api.py", line 681, in call_kw
return call_kw_multi(method, model, args, kwargs)
File "/home/kristian/.virtualenvs/odoov10/lib/python2.7/site-packages/odoo-10.0rc1c_20161005-py2.7.egg/odoo/api.py", line 672, in call_kw_multi
result = method(recs, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/kristian/.virtualenvs/odoov10/lib/python2.7/site-packages/odoo-10.0rc1c_20161005-py2.7.egg/odoo/models.py", line 2995, in read
values[name] = field.convert_to_read(record[name], record, use_name_get)
File "/home/kristian/.virtualenvs/odoov10/lib/python2.7/site-packages/odoo-10.0rc1c_20161005-py2.7.egg/odoo/models.py", line 5171, in __getitem__
return self._fields[key].__get__(self, type(self))
File "/home/kristian/.virtualenvs/odoov10/lib/python2.7/site-packages/odoo-10.0rc1c_20161005-py2.7.egg/odoo/fields.py", line 860, in __get__
self.determine_value(record)
File "/home/kristian/.virtualenvs/odoov10/lib/python2.7/site-packages/odoo-10.0rc1c_20161005-py2.7.egg/odoo/fields.py", line 969, in determine_value
self.compute_value(recs)
File "/home/kristian/.virtualenvs/odoov10/lib/python2.7/site-packages/odoo-10.0rc1c_20161005-py2.7.egg/odoo/fields.py", line 924, in compute_value
self._compute_value(records)
File "/home/kristian/.virtualenvs/odoov10/lib/python2.7/site-packages/odoo-10.0rc1c_20161005-py2.7.egg/odoo/fields.py", line 918, in _compute_value
self.compute(records)
File "/home/kristian/odoov10/gilda/l10n_ve_fiscal_requirements/model/partner.py", line 72, in _get_uid_country
res = {}.fromkeys(self._get_country_code())
File "/home/kristian/odoov10/gilda/l10n_ve_fiscal_requirements/model/partner.py", line 51, in _get_country_code
user_company = self.env['res.users'].browse(company_id)
NameError: global name 'company_id' is not defined
```

I'm new into v10 API

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's give you following error:

```
ValueError: Expected singleton: res.partner(1, 33, 8, 18, 22, 23)'
```

I think, you have added field in list/tree view. As per your current code, you didn't iterate record-sets.

If you want to keep your original code with improvements *self.company_id* then we should remove field from list/tree view. Other then you can move forward with my answer. It will work fine.

Try with following code:

```
@api.depends('company_id')
def _get_country_code(self):
    """
    Return the country code of the user company. If not exists, return XX.
    """
    context = dict(self._context or {})
    for partner in self:
        user_company = self.env['res.company'].browse(self.company_id)
        #NOTE: replace code name with your real field name where you want to see value 
        partner.code = user_company.partner_id and user_company.partner_id.country_id \
            and user_company.partner_id.country_id.code or 'XX'
```

Comment: Hi @Odedra seems a nice approach, but keeps giving me the same error, gonna make some other tests :/

Comment: Gonna open a new question, Thank You

Answer (score 1):

You need to access company_id as a member

```
user_company = self.env['res.users'].browse(self.company_id)
```

Comment: Hi, Thank You very much, but now it says 'raise ValueError("Expected singleton: %s" % self)
ValueError: Expected singleton: res.partner(1, 33, 8, 18, 22, 23)' :/ Do You know why please?

Comment: It's on that very same modified line

Answer (score 1):

@NeoVe,

> but now it says 'raise ValueError("Expected singleton: %s" % self) ValueError: Expected singleton: res.partner(1, 33, 8, 18, 22, 23)' :/ Do You know why please?

you can try adding @api.one or @api.model decorator instead of @api.multi for the function declaration.